# How to run workflow multiple times on same form

Tags: workflow, infopath, designer-workflow, forms-services

Here is my scenario in steps ,I have a InfoPath form with 4 different views view1 view2 view 3 and view4.

1. I have submit on view1 once clicked on it ,workflow will kick-off and will send an email to User1
2. In email User1 has View2 with extra field to fill and clicks submit in view2 this will send email to the initiator with new view3
3. Initiator will check the view3 and he has an extra field and fills it if everything looks fine if not he has an extra button reevaluate once clicked will send back the view2 form to the user1 to fill the form back again(as in step2)
4. if the initiator submits it, it means he has accepted the form and an email should be sent to the user1 saying he accepted it
5. view4 will be shown to initator once he clicks on submit and he fills the  view4 and submit and this will be saved to list. 
   My question is I have workflow shich is sedning the view2 to the user1 as mentioned in step 2. But once he fills and clciks submit now an email should be sent to initator. Do i need to write new workflow for this.
   Again once initator gets the view3 he has submit and reevaluate as mentioned in step 3 if submit is clicked by initator an email sent to user1 confirming he accepted it if not  view2 will be sent bakc to user1. how do i follow the workflow or this situation I am very confused.
   And all the data is stored in single list.
   Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a status column on the list and change the column value based on the view. In the workflow check the value of this status column and perform the appropriate action.

Comment: To add to @Akhoy's answer, you can create this in one workflow using status as conditions. Under those status conditions, put the email notifications and other actions that fall on that specific status.